# Is tobbaco Kitniyos?

Tags: passover, tobacco-cig-smoking, kitniyos-semigrain-legume

Is tobbaco Kitniyos?

Comment: WOw irt seems like I Have opened a whole new can of worms here

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't see why the tobacco plant itself should be kitniyos. It's nowhere on [this list](http://www.kashrut.com/Passover/kitniot_list/); I'm unaware of any grain, semigrain, legume, or the like that can be made from the tobacco plant; and tobacco's closest edible cousins ([botanically speaking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solanaceae)) are potatoes, tomatoes, peppers, and eggplants -- all of which are generally eaten on Pesach.

I have no clue how tobacco is processed, flavored, modified, etc. before it makes its way into tobacco products, though. But I can see no reason why the plant itself should be kitniyos.